# Is there a name for this ideal constructed in terms of two submodules?

Tags: commutative-algebra, terminology

If $M$ is an $R$-module and $M_1, M_2$ are submodules of $M$, then one can construct the ideal $\{ r \in R \mid rM_2 \subseteq M_1 \}$, which is denoted $(M_1 : M_2)$. Does this construction have a name?

Comment: The notation probably originates from the [ideal quotient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_quotient), but I've never heard a name for this extension.

Comment: I would probably call it an annihilator if I had to choose a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would call it the *residual* $(M_1:M_2)$ because of some papers I encountered by Ward, Dilworth and others that were oriented around [residuated lattices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residuated_lattice).

To keep the story short, I'll just say that they were abstracting commutative ring ideas out to the study of the lattice of ideals. The residual can be used to make a [residuated mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residuated_mapping) on the lattice of ideals of a ring.

Residuals pop up with different terminology and in tangential ideas:

- If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are ideals in a ring, then it is also called the **ideal quotient**. I have also seen **transporter** and **conductor** applied, even when $M_1$ is merely a *set*.
- When $M_1=\{0\}$ this is just another way of writing the **annihilator** of $M_2$. In fact you can think of it this way in general: $(M_1:M_2)=\mathrm{ann}((M_2+M_1)/M_1)$.
- When $M_1$ is a right ideal of a ring, then $(M_1:M_1)$ (as you have defined it) is the **idealizer** of $M_1$. It is the largest subring of $R$ in which $M_1$ is a two-sided ideal.

Comment: Though if we call $(I:J)$ ideal quotient I wonder why we don't call $(M:N)$ a module quotient.

Comment: @MattN. I haven't encountered it that way, but that would be a good name for it. "Residual" is really the way lattice theorists think of it.

Comment: @MattN. My worry is that forming the quotient or factor module out of modules $M_1 \subset M_2$ seems deserving of that name as well.

Comment: @DylanMoreland Indeed. OTOH, aren't there other cases where one word means two completely different things?

Comment: @MattN. Numerous cases, but we don't need to be adding fuel to the fire if we can help it :)

Comment: @rschwieb I couldn't agree more. OTOH, calling $(I:J)$ "ideal quotient" and $(M:N)$ not "module quotient" hurts my feelings : )

Comment: @MattN. You're welcome to hop on the "residual" bandwagon at any time!